# How do I crop a widget, or cut out a square portion of a widget of that particular size?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to crop a `CameraPreview` widget, so that I only get the **exact size and position where I want to cut it.**

Currently I am able to clip it using `ClipRect`, 
but i get this black area around where widget was clipped out which I want to remove ( see my replacement for a good graphic below )

Lets say we have a widget like this

```
 --------------                       
|88888888888888|                               
|88888888888888|                   
|88888888888888|                     
|88888888888888|                      
|88888888888888|                     
|88888888888888|                     
 --------------
```

I need to crop the widget, (not clip)

```
 --------------                       
|              |                               
|              |                    
|         888  |                      -----
|         888  |                     | 888 | 
|         888  |                     | 888 | 
|              |                     | 888 |
 --------------                       -----
     CLIPPING                        CROPPING
```

Can anyone help me with cropping a widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind i managed to solve it on my own,
It felt like flutter framework works in mysterious ways until i figured this out

```
return Container( // just a parent
      child: Align( // important
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container( // just a parent
          width: some_width,  
          height: some_height,  
          child: SizedBox(
            width: width,  // final width of cropped portion
            height: width,  // final height of cropped portion
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment(-1,-1), // gives you top left portion of the size above, (1,1) gives bottom right, right direction is positive x, downward direction is positive y, see about Alignment on flutter docs for more details 
              maxWidth: double.infinity,
              maxHeight: double.infinity,
              child: Container(
                width: width,
                height: width,
                child: ClipRect(
                  clipper: RectClipper(i, width / 4),// this is a custom clipper i made of type CustomClipper<Rect>
                  child: CameraPreview(controller),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: What does the RectClipper do? Does it set the offset into the widget for clipping?

Comment: can you also provide the code for RectClipper(), It is also part of the answer.

Comment: Could you please include the custom RectClipper code? I have the same problem and can't find a solution to it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to cut Transform.scale (because when I zoomed the image got out of the bounds). In my case [ScaleAnimator] implements Transform.scale logic. So I created simple implementation of CustomClipper:

```
class RectCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) => Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) => oldClipper != this;
}
```

And used it like this:

```
ClipRect(
  clipper: RectCustomClipper(),
  child: ScaleAnimator(
    child: MapLayout(
      offsetController: widget.mapControllerImpl,
      mapProperties: widget.mapControllerImpl.mapProperties,
      coordinateBuilder: widget.coordinateBuilder,
    ),
  ),
)
```

This solution helped me in case when Transform.scale ignored SafeArea and got out of the bounds.

---

And another example of cutting the image (if you need to show only some wanted part of image:

1. Using same clipper:

```
class RectCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) => Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) => oldClipper != this;
}
```

2. Some pseudo code (insert your image widget here):

```
const double imageOffsetDx = 200

return SizedBox(
                width: imageOffsetDx ,
                child: OverflowBox(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  maxWidth: double.infinity,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: imageOffsetDx ,
                    child: ClipRect(
                      clipper: RectCustomClipper(),
                      child: Image(*your image here*),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
final Size size = controller.value.size;
return ClipRect(
  child: OverflowBox(
    maxWidth: double.infinity,
    maxHeight: double.infinity,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: CameraPreview(controller)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I tried this but this is for center cropping, i want to crop the widget at the exact position and size i want.